# Registration form and removing all fields

Tags: html, forms, twitter-bootstrap, registration

When someone do not fill all fields in my formular the site is showing error and it is refreshing so that someone must fill it again.

How to make the site remember correctly filled fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the form is submitted, then on page refresh the `$_POST` data is still intact. So what you can do is something like this:

```
<input type="text" name="field_name" value="<?php echo (isset($_POST['field_name']) ? $_POST['field_name'] : ''); ?>">
```

What it does is that if the `$_POST` data for the field `field_name` is set, then echo its value.

Answer (score 0):

Use of autocomplete can preserve your previous inputs.

Autocomplete ON will preserve the value and OFF will prevent the input box from remembering. In sample code, email have off as autocomplete.

```
<input autocomplete="on|off">
```

OR

```
<form action="/action" autocomplete="on">
  First name:<input type="text" name="fname"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
  E-mail: <input type="email" name="email" autocomplete="off"><br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```